# Meteor js condition with each loop

Tags: javascript, meteor, foreach, conditional-statements

I am very new to meteor js and trying to build a small messaging app.

What I want to do is I want to check a condition within the loop with

Probably, something like this.

```
<div class="messages-box">
{{#each messages}}

    {{#if isCurrentUserCan}}
        <p>{{msg that user can do bla bla}}</p>
    {{else}}
        <p>{{msg that user can't do}}</p>
    {{/if}}

    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

js

```
Template.body.helpers({
'isCurrentUserCan': function(){
  if ( random message box's user ID == Meteor.userId() ){
      return 'This user can do bla bla';
 }else{
      return 'This user can't do';
 }
}
});
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating over a collection of messages. Let's say that each message includes a `userId` key. You can check to see if the `userId` of the message is the same as the current user and return true or false accordingly.

```
Template.body.helpers({
  'isCurrentUserCan'() {
    return this.userId === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

Inside the `{{each}}` `this` is set to the current `message` object so `this.key` directly accesses the corresponding key.